# upvoting tech support questions

Tags: discussion

I have been closing some tech support questions lately but there seems to be someone out there that is upvoting them. Since they are off-topic, shouldn't they be downvoted and flagged (or I come across it and close it)?

Here is an example I closed recently: [Where can I find information on a digital picture frame?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/where-can-i-find-information-on-a-digital-picture-frame)

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic questions should be closed, for sure. I don't know if I'd go so far as to say "downvote every off-topic question", since it might be a good question for a different site -- or simply a good question (well-written, researched, etc) that's just off-topic here.

Comment: I agree but at least don't upvote them. I would say in that case flag it so one of the mods can transfer it